# How to delete an element which has a key which contains a certain substing using jq?

Tags: json, key, jq, del

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "Category": [
    {
      "SomeKey_1": {
        "Property1": 1,
        "Property2": false
      }
    },
    {
      "SomeKey_2": {
        "Property1": 2,
        "Property2": true
      }
    },
    {
      "OtherKey_1": {
        "Property1": 3,
        "Property2": false
      }
    },
    {
      "OtherKey_2": {
        "Property1": 4,
        "Property2": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and I would like to delete from the Category[] array those element whose key starts with or contains "Other".
So as the result I would like to have this:

```
{
  "Category": [
    {
      "SomeKey_1": {
        "Property1": 1,
        "Property2": false
      }
    },
    {
      "SomeKey_2": {
        "Property1": 2,
        "Property2": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use the Select command but there I am able to select based on the values not the keys.

Comment: Will there only be a single property per object? What do you want to do when there are multiple properties in an object, some starting with "Other", others not starting with "Others"? e.g. `{"Category": [ { "SomeKey_1": {}, "OtherKey2": {} } ] }` – what would the output be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the objects in your array only contain a single property:

```
.Category |= map(select(keys_unsorted[0] | contains("Other") | not))
```

If you want to delete objects of which any property's key starts with "Other":

```
.Category |= map(select(any(keys_unsorted[]; contains("Other")) | not))
```

And finally, if you only want to delete those objects with only "Other" properties:

```
.Category |= map(select(all(keys_unsorted[]; contains("Other")) | not))
```

It's also possible to use the `del` filter:

```
del(.Category[] | select(keys_unsorted[0] | contains("Other")))
del(.Category[] | select(any(keys_unsorted[]; contains("Other"))))
del(.Category[] | select(all(keys_unsorted[]; contains("Other"))))
```

Comment: Okay, this selects the desired elements, but how to delete them from the original JSON? I mean my JSON does not only contain this content I wrote here.

Comment: @TamásVarga sorry, I was missing a `| not` filter!

Comment: As the full condition was "starts with or contains" (with the latter already meeting the former), you could replace `startswith` with `contains`.

Comment: @pmf right, I missed the "contains" part of the question; I thought it was "starts with" only. Fixed now